# Tensorflow: sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, tensorflow

I have an image multilabel classification problem that I would like to solve with tensorflow.

I'm trying to construct proper loss function and a "proper" final layer for CNN network.

What kind of arguments the

```
tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels, logits)
```

function expects?

Am I safe to assume that:

- labels are vectors with binary values {0,1}
- logits are vectors with same dimmension as labels with values from whole ]-∞, ∞[

Therefore I should skip ReLU in the last layer (to ensure final output can be negative).

Or maybe logits are bounded and represent probabilty?

I'm not 100% sure on this.

Comment: `labels` are not one-hot vector but only a scalar for binary classification. unless there are multiple-label within one training sample such as both labels elephant and cat can appear in one image, then `labels` will be a vector.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are right. Your label though can be any real number between *0* and *1*, even though it would be either or usually. But in theory (and practice occasionally) labels here can be any real number in the range *[0,1]*.

For what regards the logits: No activation. You are right.

The `sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits` function uses the logistic loss as:

[image]

`x` being your logit. You basically already have the activation in that `sigmoid`-part.

Comment: Thanks, in Udacity (internet learning platform) logit was considered to be something with values that could represent probability so [0,1], that nomenclature was source of my confusion.